# Copy descriptors in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I need a descriptor for a method in order to inject into it (https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:mixin_injects). Normally I would write these descriptors by hand. But it is such a logical process that I feel like Eclipse should have it built-in.

Is there any way to copy a method descriptor in Eclipse from the method signature?

Here is a method I need a descriptor for.

[image: The public void tickChunk(WorldChunk chun, int randomTickSpeed) method signature in Eclipse.]

The descriptor should look like this: `tickChunk(Lnet/minecraft/world/chunk/WorldChunk;I)V`

Comment: Are those descriptors minecraft-related? Why dhould eclipse have explicit support for Minecraft-specific stuff?

Comment: I've never seen those "descriptors" you are talking about. You are probably looking for Minecraft related stuff in Eclipse. As @dan1st said, Eclipse would not have that built in but, there may be a plugin for it. Try looking at the Eclipse Marketplace. If you can't find one, look at the other IDE's plugin marketplaces'.

Comment: @DogaOruc This is a "method descriptor" which is defined in the Java class file format. It is how a method is described in a class file, it is standard Java (JVMS §4.3.3)

Comment: @dan1st This is a standard Java class file "method descriptor", it is not MineCraft specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can see method descriptors if you the open the .class file compiled from your .java file using the "class file editor". The descriptors are included as comments.

For example, this a `main` method as shown in the class file editor:

```
// Method descriptor #15 ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
// Stack: 4, Locals: 3
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args)
```

Comment: The class files are part of an external library. How would I go about opening them in Eclipse?

Comment: If the jar is on the Build Path of the project it will appear in the "Referenced Libraries" section in the project. You can then see (and open) the class files in the jar.

Comment: The class files have source attached and I couldn't find any way of opening them without it. No comments in the source code.